# Remove a comma in a number in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

My data contains numbers like 100,000.89 and so on. What function should I use in Redshift to remove the comma and keep it like 100000.89? Do we write the function while creating a table since it is at column level or after its creation and then post process the table?

Comment: Numbers do not contain commas in their internal storage so your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: If it looks like that it's not a number it's a text field of some sort.

Comment: I had loaded all the data with varchar just so the load process won't fail initially

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove commas from *text* columns, use `replace()`:

```
select replace(col, ',', '')
from t
```

**EDIT :** In case of `null` data use `coalesce()` :

```
select coalesce(replace(col,',', ''), '')
from t
```

Comment: Any idea on how to use this replace function if i have null in my data ?

Comment: @PrajaktaYerpude. . .  Use `coalesce()` for `null` data.

Comment: Yogesh, coalesce() works here, thanks :) However in my query below,
`insert into test.tracking_final (lease_expense)
(select 
coalesce(replace(lease_expense,',','')) as lease_expense from test.tracking)`
I still am getting Missing data for not null field. PS: I had allowed NULL in columns while creating both the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I just added all the columns in my insert query with coalesce since all of them somewhere had null values and it worked like a charm. The redshift error for missing data in not null fields is misleading here as mentioned : https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=119640
I changed my copy command too, and added BLANKSASNULL. This worked! Thanks for all your help. Below is my command: 
    `insert into test.t_final 
    (select 
    coalesce(project_number) as project_number,
    coalesce(contract_po) as contract_po,
    coalesce(tracking_date) as tracking_date,
    (coalesce(replace(amount,',',''))) as amount,
    (coalesce(replace(tax,',',''))) as tax,
    (coalesce(replace(contract_value,',',''))) as contract_value,
    coalesce(comments) from test.t)`